# PHP unix time stamp in the past

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I always struggled with this, making a unix time stamp in the past, I need to find all records in mysql that are older than 30 days, but can't seem to think of a way to do this without writing a lot of code, there must be a short way to do it?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is there a date field on the records you want to search for?

Comment: am I right that now no any time info in old records ?

Comment: Does every record has a field with the creation timestamp?

Comment: Just let MySQL handle the arithmatics with something like `NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY`?`

Comment: umm theres a field that is called 'time' to default value of it is now() so it gets time stamped ever time new records get entered

Comment: MySQL has perfectly good DATE and DATETIME formats - there's no good reason I can think of for storing values as unix timestamps and lots of drawbacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

```
select * from mytable where time <
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP/MySQL:

```
$thirtydaysago = time() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 30);

$query = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE time < '$thirtydaysago'";
```

Comment: While this is only a slightly different approach than using DATE_SUB, I'm in favor of it for the clarity. I might have to support this someday. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the PHP mktime function, pass in the date you want and away you go:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Answer (score 0):

I would use the mysql `DATEDIFF` function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

with `NOW()` as one of the arguments. The number of days between the dates is returned.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a datafield so you can use something like mysql DATE_SUB to resolve:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```